# Selenium WebDriver how to get Button for WebElement

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML code from a website login.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn ow-btn-primary btn-block-xs pull-right">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
     "Log On"
</button>
```

and I want to be able to access the button in selenium. What code would I need in order to call upon it in java?

Comment: 1) Show the code that you have done so far. 2) What have you done to find the answer? What documentation or article have you read or what tutorial have you accomplished before asking this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` to identify the Button element.

```
//button[@class='btn ow-btn-primary btn-block-xs pull-right' and contains(.,'Log On')]
```

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable`()

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);         
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn ow-btn-primary btn-block-xs pull-right' and contains(.,'Log On')]")));
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below statement to locate the element

```
WebElement submitBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Log On']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@type='Submit' and contains(.,'Log On')]")));
element.click();

Answer (score -1):

You probably can copy its xPath and use following code:

```
WebElement submit_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath goes here");
```

If you then want to press the buton try:

```
submit_button.click();
```